# Ruby 1.9.3 wont install?

Tags: ruby, macos

Im having a problem installing Ruby 1.9.3, i dont know if it matters but im using ML POST FACTOR to run os x 10.8 on my older mac

Here is the error im getting

```
tylers-macbook:~ Tyler$ rvm install 1.9.3
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p547..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p547.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p547, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p547 to /Users/Tyler/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547....
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #applying patch /Users/Tyler/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p547 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Tyler/.rvm/log/1408657159_ruby-1.9.3-p547/configure.log
[2014-08-21 17:39:40] ./configure
current path: /Users/Tyler/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/Tyler/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Tyler/.rvm/bin:/Users/Tyler/.rvm/bin
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Tyler/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

thanks for taking the time to help

config.log

```
8/21/14 6:07:04.844 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.sleepservicesd[24476]) Exited: Killed: 9
8/21/14 6:07:04.000 PM kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 24476 [SleepServicesD]
8/21/14 6:07:04.910 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[21]) Exited: Killed: 9
8/21/14 6:07:05.000 PM kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 21 [cfprefsd]
8/21/14 6:07:48.225 PM md5[26610]: BUG in libdispatch:  - 1879 - 0x1b
8/21/14 6:07:48.274 PM md5[26613]: BUG in libdispatch:  - 1879 - 0x1b
```

Comment: It says "See config.log for more details", so did you look in config.log?  If you did and you don't understand it, posting it here would help us help you.

Comment: ok thanks i will post

Comment: Do you have the latest xcode installed with the command line tools?

Comment: i cant install xcode 6 because i dont have os x 10.9.x - 10.10.x

Comment: You are running a pre-release, beta version of an operating system. I'm sorry, but what do you expect?

Comment: what? im running 10.8.4

Comment: Can you install newer versions of ruby?

Comment: You need a c compiler installed. The easiest way is to install Xcode and its command line tools. You should be able to install Xcode 5 on 10.8.4.

Comment: i installed the command line tools and it worked thanks guys :)

Comment: It might have compiled, but if you used the default Xcode compiler then it has been built with errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you either don't have a C compiler, or the C compiler you're using doesn't understand some of the flags used by RVM.

Also, the log you quoted is the wrong one. The error has been logged in `/Users/Tyler/.rvm/log/1408657159_ruby-1.9.3-p547/configure.log`.

### About the compiler.

Some users have suggested in the comments to install Xcode.
You do need to install Xcode to do software development on your mac (because it also installs other CLI utilities), but you should not use the default Xcode compiler to build Ruby MRI 1.9.3.

The Xcode compiler is `clang` (`llvm`), but Ruby MRI 1.9 only supports `gcc` (another older but widely used compiler).
While it's true that MRI 1.9.3 is *unofficially* compatible with `clang`, there are some known issues and some modules do not compile correctly (Fibers).

Full `clang` support has been added with MRI 2.0.0.

So, if you really want to install MRI 1.9.3, you need to install `gcc` first:

```
brew update
brew install gcc-4.9

rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9
```